# Apparent contradiction of a functional variation of a non-symmetric tensor wrt the metric

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

Lets say after some calculations I arrive at the following expression

$
\int\mathrm{d}^4x\sqrt{-g} (T_{\mu\nu}+T_{\nu\mu})\delta g^{\mu\nu} = 0,
$

where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is non-symmetric and $g^{\mu\nu}$ are the components of the metric. As it is, this implies that

$
T_{\mu\nu} + T_{\nu\mu}= 0.
$

But, since the metric is symmetric, one could relabel the dummy indices and get

$
2\int\mathrm{d}^4x\sqrt{-g} T_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu} = 0,
$

which implies $T_{\mu\nu}=0$. So apparently there's something wrong that leads to different results. What is the source of this mistake? I feel that the answer is to do with Langrange multipliers, but I am not quite sure. Should I assume the metric is not symmetric while taking the variation and only in the end that I take it as being symmetric? Why there is no apparent problem when $T_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

If $T_{\mu\nu}$ is an anti-symmetric tensor and metric is symmetric, then after the result that multiplication of an anti-symmetric tensor with a symmetric tensor gives zero, ( i.e.

$$
T_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}=- T_{\nu\mu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}=- T_{\nu\mu} \delta g^{\nu\mu}=- T_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} \\
\Rightarrow \quad T_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}=0 \, ) 
$$

the integrand would be automatically zero, if $T_{\mu\nu}$ is anti-symmetric.

And, remember if $T_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric, then you get the same expression.

And $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ is a special result of $T_{\mu\nu}+T_{\nu\mu}=0$, since the former satisfies the latter. So, why do you think the result is wrong?

Comment: You haven't addressed any of my questions. First off, I said non-symmetric (meaning arbitrary) and not anti-symmetric. Second, the symmetry of the metric might impose a constraint to the variation, that was my initial concern. Otherwise, the variation of any anti-symmetric tensor, as you've calculated, would be trivially zero. Lastly, the 'former' implies the 'latter', but the opposite doesn't hold, so they're not equivalent.

Comment: @Mr.K Ok. I have just worded it wrong, see edited version. Of course the "latter" is not the same as the "former". These are not different results, since the next integral is the next step of calculation and your calculation shows that $T_{\mu\nu}$ should vanish.

Comment: $T_{\mu\nu}+T_{\nu\mu}=0$ has clearly more information than $T_{\mu\nu}=0$, so they *are* different results! My point is that the passage from the first integral to the second one is not right, and I suspect that's because of the presence of a constraint, namely the symmetry of the metric. I just would like to know if I'm right.

Comment: @Mr.K.Ok. Of course, symmetry of the metric tensor imposes constraint on the variation, for instance the variation of an antisymmetric tensor w.r.t. a symmetric tensor (here the metric) has consequences. Variation of an antisymmetric tensor w.r.t. an arbitrary tensor does not vanish in general.